# Two rust hiccups - Unknown size of Fn & Closure is FnOnce

Tags: rust

I want to create a generic function that takes a path to a directory and crawls over it, applying an optional function to each of the files found in this directory and each of the subdirectories.

I have hit a dead end on 2 cases that I don't understand.

**This is the first case.** I'm applying functions to just one directory, but don't know how to type my `None` cases:

```
fn main() {

    fn file_fn (file: &str) {
        println!("file: {:?}", file)
    }

    fn dir_fn (file: &str) {
        println!("dir:  {:?}", file)
    }

    // Passing case 
    apply_dir(".", Some(file_fn), Some(dir_fn));

    // Failing case
    apply_dir(".", Some(file_fn), None::<dyn Fn(&str)>);
                               // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time

}


fn apply_dir<F, G> (dir: &str, file_func: Option<F>, dir_func: Option<G>)
where F: Fn(&str), G: Fn(&str) {
    for path in read_dir(dir).unwrap() {
        if path.is_dir() {
            match dir_func {
                Some(ref func) => func(path.to_str().unwrap()),
                _ => (),
            }
        } else {
            match file_func {
                Some(ref func) => func(path.to_str().unwrap()),
                _ => (),
            }
        }
    }
}


fn read_dir(dir: &str) -> io::Result<Vec<PathBuf>> {

    let mut paths = fs::read_dir(dir)?
        .map(|res| res.map(|e| e.path()))
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, io::Error>>()?;

    paths.sort();
    Ok(paths)
}
```

I have `dyn` in the type because it does it automatically anyway, and not stating it will deprecate someday, but I don't know what that does.

**This is the second case.** I'm trying to crawl the directory and apply the function to every file in the subdirectories.

```
fn main() {

    fn file_fn (file: &str) {
        println!("file: {:?}", file)
    }

    crawl_dir(".", Some(file_fn));
}


// --- same apply_dir and read_dir functions


fn crawl_dir<F> (dir: &str, file_func: Option<F>)
where F: Fn(&str) {
    apply_dir(dir, file_func, Some(|f| crawl_dir(f, file_func)));
 // ---------                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------^
 // |                              |                |
 // |                              |                closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `file_func` out of its environment
 // |                              this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `Fn`
 // the requirement to implement `Fn` derives from here
}
```

I mostly understand this error, but I don't know how to fix it.

Ownership of `file_func` is taken by the closure and it's getting consumed by the closure, making it `FnOnce`. I don't find how to make a closure pass as `Fn`, even when I pass no arguments into it from outside of its scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dyn` is describing that a certain type has some functionality, bit does not say anything about the data of the type, Therefore doesn't say anything about the size.

`dyn Fn(&str)` Is staying that the type being passed in can be called with a `&str` argument, but that is not enough to determine how much memory needs to be allocated for that type. For example, both

```
let a = |file: &str| {
    println!("dir:  {:?}", file)
};
```

and

```
let prefix = "dir: ";
let b = |file: &str| {
    println!("{}{:?}", &prefix, file)
};
```

adhere to `dyn func(&str)`, but `b` takes up more space because it also needs to store the refrence to `prefix`.

To fix your first issue, you can pass in a type that has a fixed size, such as a `fn(&str)` function pointer.

```
apply_dir(".", Some(file_fn), None::<fn(&str)>);
```

As for the second issue, it is saying because the closure is taking ownership of `file_func`

```
Some(|f| crawl_dir(f, file_func)))
```

after this closure is called `file_func` will no longer be able to be used, but you are needing to call this closure multiple times (once for each file), and therefore needs to use `file_func` multiple times. So the ownership of `file_func` needs to stay out of that closure.

If you use refrences instead, then the closure will not take ownership and the it can be called multiple times.

```
fn main() {
    crawl_dir(".", &Some(file_fn));
}

fn crawl_dir<F> (dir: &str, file_func: &Option<F>)
    where F: Fn(&str) {
    apply_dir(dir, file_func, Some(|f: &str| crawl_dir(f, file_func)));
}
fn apply_dir<F, G> (dir: &str, file_func: &Option<F>, dir_func: Option<G>)
where F: Fn(&str), G: Fn(&str) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Why are you able to put `fn(&str)` within angle brackets? What is it telling rust?

Comment: @v4gil `fn(&str)` is the type of a function pointer. `Some(file_fn)` has the type of `Option<fn(&str)>`. Function pointers just like any other pointers have a fixed size.

Comment: @v4gil as @Riwen pointed out, you could also use `None::<&dyn Fn(&str)>` because references are rusts abstractions over pointers, so references also have fixed sizes.

Answer (score 0):

`dyn Fn(&str)` is a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html), ie. any concrete type that implements `Fn(&str)`, therefore it's a dynamically-sized type, so it doesn't have a size that is known at compile time (because it could be implemented by many types, with various sizes). The solution here would be to either box it: `Box<dyn Fn(&str)>`, or just use it behind a pointer: `<&dyn Fn(&str)`. Thus, basically, making a (fat, or wide) pointer.